# Why specify different vertex formats for one attribute?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

The OpenGL functions `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glVertexAttribFormat` allow the user to specify the format for data which will be bound to a given attribute variable in the shader program when rendering.  Vertex attribute format is information like the data type (`int`, `float`, `byte`, etc), the number of dimensions in the attribute variable (`vec2`, `vec3`, etc), whether the data ought to be normalized, and the offset into the vertex array for the start position of the array of data.  These functions specify the format when one is building a vertex array object (VAO), and the specified format is part of the state of the VAO.  So here is my question:

Why is the format of the data to be associated with the attribute a part of the state of the VAO, and not a part of the state of the attribute?  In other words, why is the format of the data associated with the VAO rather than the attribute?  Under what circumstances will I have VAOs which use different formats for the same attribute?

For more clarity, here is an example which should illustrate why I'm confused.  Imagine in my vertex shader I declare the variable:

```
in vec3 position;
```

Now I'm getting the attribute location in my OpenGL application:

```
GLint positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(myProgram, "position");
```

Now when I create a VAO, and I specify the data format like this:

```
glVertexAttribFormat(positionAttribute​, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE​, 0);
```

Since the format is associated with the VAO, every time I create a VAO I have to specify the format.  The 'position' attribute is `vec3`, so I will always specify 3 and `GL_FLOAT` to `glVertexAttribFormat`.  So why is OpenGL designed in this way, so that I potentially have to call `glVertexAttribFormat` every time I create a VAO, and specify a format which will remain constant?  It seems to me that I should have specified the format when I called `glGetAttribLocation`, so that I only do it once.

Comment: Mind to elaborate? What do you mean with "state of the attribute"?

Comment: In other words, why is the format of the data associated with the VAO rather than the attribute?  When you call `glVertexAttribFormat` to specify the format of the data, you need to have a VAO bound, because that format is associated with the VAO.  I'm asking why the format isn't associated with the attribute itself, instead.  This is because I can't imagine a scenario where I would use a different attribute format for different data.  The attribute is statically typed in the shader.  Is this clearer?  I'll probably add this info to the question.

Comment: I also edited in an example which will hopefully illustrate what I mean.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're asking why attribute settings (size, stride, etc.) are stored on the VAO and not the shader program. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. My original thought was why not on the attribute, but shader program also seems like it would make more sense then the VAO.  Also I'm mostly talking about type, length, normalization, and perhaps the relative offset.  Stride is contingent on the format of the buffer, so I see why that is not associated with the attribute / shader program.

Comment: For some context, you should know that OpenGL is designed purposely with the ability to mismatch vertex attribute format. For instance, if you declare a vertex attribute in GLSL as `vec4` and then use a 1D vertex attribute pointer, in GLSL you will read the following per-vertex `(x, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. In fact, this is why you should always declare position attributes as `vec4`; GL will automatically assign the homogeneous `w` coordinate a value of **1.0** and make writing any matrix transformations much easier for you (_e.g._ no more pointless stuff like `matrix * vec4 (pos, 1.0)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, design decisions are made in every API. There mostly isn't only one way to accomplish a given task, and to some degree this is just the way it was defined in this case.

I don't have any direct insight on the decision making behind this, but can think of a few considerations that provide valid motivation for this one.

- **Operation without shaders** : OpenGL has evolved over a long time. Shaders were not part of the API initially, and there are still versions of the API that can operate without shaders (Compatibility Profile). If there are no shaders, your idea of deriving the type of the attributes from shader attributes would not work at all.
- **Support for data types that do not correspond to GLSL types**: While using something like `vec4` in the shader and `GL_FLOAT` for the attribute specification is most common, it's not the only option. For example, attributes can be specified as `GL_HALF_FLOAT` or crazy formats like `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV`. These formats have possible uses if you really want to save memory for your vertex data. Or if you already have the vertices in this format, for example because you're porting Direct3D code, which supports them. These formats do not directly correspond to types in GLSL, so they could not be supported without specifying the attribute type explicitly.
- **Dependency between vertex setup state and program state**: This is more conceptual. The way it works now, vertex setup state and program state is orthogonal. Avoiding dependency between concepts that do not *have* to be dependent is always a good design goal. If vertex attribute formats depend on the currently bound program, you break this independence. For example, when a new program is bound, the interpretation of vertex attribute data could change, which means that the vertex setup state would have to be updated. These kinds of state dependencies are very undesirable due to the resulting complexity and inefficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself what happens when they don't match.

This allows to specify storage data structure that differ from the in-shader usage itself. So say you store packed rgba8, you still likely want to do floating point math with it. so you declare it as vec4 in the shader, but use RGBA8 as your vertex data format. And GL will do conversion between the 2 formats for you.

Answer (score 0):

So what happens if you have more than one attribute? Or what if you want to store Position, Color, and Normals? This in my experience applies specifically to UV coordinates.

Because then your attribute will only be size 2 not 3. Because your texture will only have 2 coordinates(Ignoring possibility of 3D textures). What if you are working in 2D. The attrib pointer allows you to specify the size of the input for that attribute more than anything else, and the type. It is useful because it allows you to change the format of the data. In any case, you should only be creating your VAO once, unless you need to rebind new data to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> "t seems to me that I should have specified the format

Uhm no, you did not specify any format, you just fetched an attribute location.

The choice there it's simply because GL gives you a lot flexibility in terms of

1. converting other data types to float for you
2. passing vectors with different sizing
3. normalizing non-float types
4. using interleaved, non-zero offset buffers for attributes

This can be only "partially" automated. Sure, you can introspect the shader and figure out that your attribute is indeed a `vec3`, so 3 floats, but still this doesn't tell GL how the data in your vertex array buffer objects looks like. Notably, it's allowed to contain

- other compatible types (note that `glVertexAttribPointer` / `glVertexAttribFormat` can take a bunch of different types, not just `GL_FLOAT`)
- data with a lower dimensionality (who tells GL that?)
- interleaved data (who tells GL what's the stride?)
- data at non-zero offsets (who tells GL what's the base offset?)
- data that may or may not need normalization (who tells GL that?)

Answer to "who tells": your call to `glVertexAttribFormat`.

Comment: You don't understand my question.  I'm not asking how or why the data format is specified.  I'm asking why the API is designed this way -- why does the API allow specification of data format per the VAO, and not per attributes.  I am well aware that the call to `glGetAttribLocation` only gets the location of the attribute, which is why I said as much directly above that line of code. I'm asking why the API not allow me to specify the format of the attribute at that point given that the data type for an attribute is defined in the shader program, and will not change (AFAIK).

Comment: Also you are incorrect.   `glVertexAttribFormat` does not allow for the specification of the stride in the buffer.  `glBindVertexBuffer` is the function which allows for this when specifying the buffer data separately from the attribute format. This is an important distinction.

Comment: Why should you specify in the *attribute* that the data should be read from a buffer in a certain "form" (type / dimensionality / offset / stride / normalization)? Do you really want to rewrite your vertex shaders for supporting different layouts in the inputs buffers? Think of using the same shader for meshes loaded from files, where the authors could have chosen any interleaving of the attributes. You can easily match 1 VAO = 1 mesh (when loading the meshes), and at the same time keep using the very same shader program.

Comment: About the stride, it's purely academic. I mentioned `glVertexAttribPointer` where you *do* pass the stride. The new `glBindVertexBuffer` + `glVertexAttribFormat` decompose that (it's all good, much more readable now). Still doesn't change the bulk of the reasoning.

Comment: The comment you wrote here is far more useful than your actual answer.  Though you still don't seem to understand that "Why should you specify in the attribute that the data should be read from a buffer in a certain "form" (type / dimensionality / offset / stride / normalization)?" was essentially the question I originally asked, I will give you +1 since the information is helpful :)

Comment: Heh, it takes a while to iterate over design questions :P